# How to Ignore warnings in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have been trying to ignore a warning while writing playbooks the scenario is i execute this `virt-host-validate qemu` and it throws up one single warning like as below.

```
root@n0:~/playbook_promenade# virt-host-validate 
QEMU: Checking for hardware virtualization : PASS
QEMU: Checking if device /dev/kvm exists :PASS
QEMU: Checking if device /dev/kvm is accessible : PASS
QEMU: Checking if device /dev/vhost-net exists : PASS
QEMU: Checking if device /dev/net/tun exists : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller support : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller mount-point : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller support : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller mount-point: PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller support : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller mount-point : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller mount-point : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'net_cls' controller support : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'net_cls' controller mount-point : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller mount-point : PASS
QEMU: Checking for device assignment IOMMU support  : WARN (No ACPI DMAR table found, IOMMU either disabled in BIOS or not supported by this hardware platform)`
```

The playbook i have written is as follows.

```
`- hosts: localhost
   sudo: yes
   tasks:
    - name: Check if Host supports Virtualization.
      command: virt-host-validate qemu 
      ignore_errors: yes
      failed_when: false
      changed_when: false
      register: host_status
    - debug:
       msg: "status: {{host_status.stdout}}"`
```

now the worrying part is if there is any other task failing apart from the warn this playbook continues as we are using `ignore_errors: yes`
can anyone please guide me how to fix it ?? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fix it with this.

```
  tasks:
   - name: Check if Host supports Virtualization.
     command: virt-host-validate qemu
     register: command_result
     failed_when:
       - "'FAIL' in command_result.stderr"
```

Comment: Maybe it is also works if the last line is `- command_result is failed` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run it as a post task on the whole role, so each task in that role will be verified, and only if it has a non-zero return code or an STDERR that contains "error" or "fail" - the task will fail.

On all of the command/shell tasks, register the output:

```
- name: A shell task
  shell: |
    # your commands ...
  register: out
```

Then on the main role, add a post-task that will check for errors after each task:

```
- name: A role of shell/command tasks
  roles:
  - role: ...
  ...
  post_tasks:
  - name: Checking if command failed, or if stderr contains errors/failures
    fail: msg={{ out.stderr.split('\n') }}
    when: out is defined and out.stderr is defined and (out.stderr | lower | regex_search('error|fail') or out.rc != 0)
```